# Symfony2 secure all subdomains

Tags: php, security, symfony, routes, firewall

I'm creating application in Symfony with dynamic subdomains.

I would like to secure every subdomain expect the www (the www is less important).

For example : foo.mydomain.com redirects to foo.mydomain.com/login

but mydomain.com shouldn't been redirected.

In the `VHost` I have this line :

```
ServerAlias : *.mydomain.com
```

I'm using the FOSUserBundle for managing users with a custom UserManager.

The firewall looks like this :

```
firewalls:
    fos:
        pattern: ^/
        host: ^\.mydomain.com
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            use_referer:                    true
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    ~

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            use_referer:                    true
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

I'm not sure if I should have two firewalls or not

The access control looks like this :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login,  roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { host: ^\.mydomain.com, path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

So I need something like *.mydomain.com with roles ROLE_USER

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The solution**:

`.mydomain.com` instead of `^\.mydomain.com`

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login,  roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { host: .mydomain.com, path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```